# How to import fs in typesrcipt?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I am trying to read api keys in .env.json file using the following code:

```
const functionConfig = () => {
  const fs = require("fs");
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(".env.json"));
};
```

But I am getting the following error:

Require statement not part of import statement @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires

I am new to typescript so any help would be appreiated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a Typescript lint, the details of which can be found [on the repository](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-var-requires.md).

> Disallows the use of require statements except in import statements (no-var-requires)

Specifically, they make the following recommendation

> Examples of incorrect code for this rule:
>
> ```
> var foo = require('foo');
> const foo = require('foo');
> let foo = require('foo');
> ```
>
> Examples of correct code for this rule:
>
> ```
> import foo = require('foo');
> require('foo');
> import foo from 'foo';
> ```

Typescript generally prefers that you use ES6-style module imports. If you can't do so, then you can place a comment of the form

```
/* eslint-disable no-var-requires */
```